# get object property by finding its class

Tags: java, android

I have game objects in an array collection, but they can be different classes. I can find the object by its coordinates:

```
Object obb = grid.getCellContent(insertObjectX, insertObjectY);
```

What I need to do is to find if obb.canBeSubmerged == true and then simply move it to another array.

The problem is that I canot get a property of that object "canBeSubmerged" because compilier does not know which class I used.

I wonder if there is a quicker way to do it then to go through `"obb.getClass() == myClass.class"` statements for each of the possible object classes.

.
.

EDIT: based on **stuckless** suggestion here is a working solution:

```
try {    
   java.lang.reflect.Field f1 = obb.getClass().getField("canBeSubmerged");
   java.lang.reflect.Field f2 = obb.getClass().getField("subObject"); 
   if (f1 != null) {       
      canBeSubmerged = f1.getBoolean(obb); 
      f2.setBoolean(obb, canBeSubmerged);
   } 
}catch (Exception e) { } 


//enter it into the submerged grid level and remove from the top grid level
if (canBeSubmerged){
    grid.removeObject(insertObjectX, insertObjectY);
    grid.putSubObjectInCell(insertObjectX, insertObjectY, obb);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `obb` object that contains the `canBeSubmerged` property is always of a particular class type, such as `MyOBB.class`, then you can do this...

```
if (obb instanceof MyOBB.class) {
    if (((MyOBB)obb).canBeSubmerged) {
       // do your work
    }
}
```

========= OR ============

Using Reflection (which will be slower)

```
try {
   Field f = obb.getClass().getField("canBeSubmerged");
   if (f!=null && f.getBoolean(obb)) {
      // do your work
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: No they can be many different classes, but they are all referenced in an array as Object class: HashMap<Integer, Object> objects = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

Comment: I added a solution using reflection as well... but to be honest, this sounds more like a problem that should be solved using a common supertype or interface.

Comment: This works! You are a genius and a truly stuck-less person! ;)
canBeSubmerged is a final (constant) variable in a derived class from a super-class GameObject, so not sure if I could get it from the superclass, but in retrospect it could be done by initialising a field with every instance. It is good to know it can be done like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your objects should probably all extend a common superclass or implement a common interface which defines a method

```
public boolean canBeSubmerged();
```

You should not use public fields. And also note that

```
if (obb.canBeSubmerged() == true)
```

can be written as

```
if (obb.canBeSubmerged())
```

which is more logical and readable.

Comment: Of course I would not make if statements with someting == true, that was a part of my text. Now, why there are public fields if they should not be used as such?

Comment: Because they can, in very rare cases, have a justification. But OO design is all about encapsulation and polymorphism, and public fields forbid encapsulation and polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in one attribute of the object your could extract that to an interface
public interface Submergable {
      boolean isSubmerged();
    }

And let all objects that may submerge implement it.

Then you can do `Object instanceof Submergable`